# mod_proxy_hcheck causes apache-2.4 startup-crash

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I would like to create a load-balanced environment using Apache 2.4.43 (windows) and two Tomcats servers.
Using the "mod_proxy_hcheck" module some basic healthcheck operations should be implemented, which are based on the official documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html

My config

```
ProxyHCExpr ok2 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[2]/}
<Proxy balancer://appcluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/app-SNAPSHOT route=server1 secret=1337 hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok2 hcinterval=10 hcpasses=2 hcfails=3
    BalancerMember http://localhost:9090/app-SNAPSHOT route=server2 secret=1337 hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok2 hcinterval=10 hcpasses=2 hcfails=3
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /app-SNAPSHOT balancer://appcluster
ProxyPassReverse /app-SNAPSHOT balancer://appcluster
```

My problem: Whenever I use any parameter documented in the mod_proxy_hcheck docs, my Server fails to start. The following error-message is logged in the Winodws Event-Viewer
The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> Invalid command 'ProxyHCExpr', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

I've played around and removed those `mod_proxy_hcheck` related params like `ProxyHCExpr, hcfails, hcpasses, hcinterval, hcexpr, hcmethod`, but whenever one is activated, the service crashes during startup.

What I've tried/searched:

- I've searched for the `mod_proxy_hcheck` module in my `httpd.conf` file, but it is not listed here. So I have checked the `<apacheInstallDir>\modules`:  The file `mod_proxy_hcheck.so` exists
- I've added the line `LoadModule proxy_hcheck_module modules/mod_proxy_hcheck.so` to my `httpd.conf`, but service-startup fails.

Any ideas left?

Comment: I was totally confused by my trail&error so I've missed the relevant hint in the ``error.log``-file: ``[Thu Aug 17 22:35:26.996830 2023] [proxy_hcheck:crit] [pid 19280:tid 768] AH03262: mod_watchdog is required``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that `LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so` is also included in the `httpd.conf` file.
This is also mentioned in the official documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html#Summary unter the "Summary" section.